# Overpass: Combine two queries

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I'm having trouble with my overpass query/queries. Goal is to create a map with (a) all traffic signals and (b) designated bike routes in Wiesbaden.

I already got the queries seperatley running but I'm facing problems when combining them. Both, traffic lights and bike routes are shown - but hundrets of nodes (I guess grom the routes) more as well. How do i get rid of them?

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
//area(3600062481)->.searchArea;

{{geocodeArea:Wiesbaden}};

// gather results

(
node["highway"="traffic_signals"](area)->.ampeln;
relation["route"="bicycle"](area)->.routen;
  );

out body;
>;
out;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the last `out;` to `out skel qt;` if you don't want every node of the bicycle routes to be highlighted.

Comment: Thanks - sometimes the solution is very easy :D